# Count data in same sentence

Tags: php, mysql

I have table :

```
==========================================================
|id | before | after | freq | id_sentence | document_id  |
==========================================================
| 1 |    a   |   b   | 1    |     0       |      1       |
| 2 |    c   |   d   | 1    |     1       |      1       |
| 3 |    e   |   f   | 1    |     1       |      1       |
| 4 |    g   |   h   | 2    |     0       |      2       |
==========================================================
```

I want to get the number of data depend on the `id_sentence` and `freq` so the result must be 1 2 1
here's the code :

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT freq FROM tb where document_id='$doc_id' ");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $stem_freq = $row['freq'];
        $total = $total+$stem_freq;
```

but the result is still wrong. please, help me.. thank you :)

Comment: And what is `stem_freq`? Not listed in the table.

Comment: @Hamish sorry, I've edited it.

Comment: @JohnWoo depends on `id_sentence`. `id_sentence` 0 has 1 data, etc

Comment: Im sure the answer would be easy but I can't figure out how you are getting "1 2 1'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, you are trying the calculate the sum of `freq` for each distinct `id_sentence` for a particular `document_id`.

Try the following SQL:

```
SELECT id_sentence, SUM(freq) as freq FROM tb WHERE document_id = 1 GROUP BY(id_sentence)
```

The result will be rows of data with the `id_sentence` and corresponding total `freq`. No need to manually sum things up afterwards.

See this SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/691ed/8

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do something like

```
SELECT count(*) AS count FROM tb GROUP BY(id_sentence,freq)
```

to do the counting you want. You could even do something like

```
SELECT count(*) AS count, id_sentence, freq FROM tb GROUP BY(id_sentence,freq)
```

to know which id_sentence,freq combination the count is for.